# Statistical test for comparing two distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions

I am observing a phenomena, to simplify it, we say the acceleration of objects, $Oi$, for which I measure the acceleration over the time with a frequency of 100HZ.

Let's imagine I did 50 experiments, producing 50 datasets. A dataset, $Di$, contains the acceleration of the object $Oi$ over the time e.g. 2 seconds. For each dataset $Di$, I can calculate the Mean, $Mi$, and the Standard Deviation, $SDi$. Therefore, each object can be described with $Oi$($Mi$,$SDi$)

Moreover, I compute the combined mean as in the following:

1) The Combined Mean : $Mc$ = $Sum(Ni∗Mi)/Sum(Ni)$
where $Ni$ is the cardinality of the dataset $Di$, per i=1...50

2) The Combined standard deviation, $SDc$, as shown in the attached pic[image] description here.

The result of the above computation is to build a acceleration model F which can be described with the combined mean $Mc$ and combined $SDc$, $F(Mc,SDc)$.

I would like to build a filter that uses F(Mc,SDc) as a model to select those experiments among others that have a complete different distribution and therefore, mean and standard deviation.

`The first question is`: What is the best statistical test to apply in order to compare $F(Mc,SDc)$ and $O(Mj,SDj)$?

`The second question is`: How I should phrase the Null Hypothesis and the Alternative Hypothesis?

`Additional info`: $F(Mc,SDc)$ can be approximate to a Gaussian but for the others, $O(Mj,SDj)$, no info.

Please any help on this would be very appreciated.

Best Regards, Carlo

Comment: I figured out the answer for the second question: H0: there is no difference between the two distributions. H1: there is a difference between the two distribution. Then, My question is: how to formulate it in terms of Mean and Standard Deviation?

Comment: Instead of putting this information in comments, try updating your original question.

Comment: Any Help, please?